# Looking for Oauth Yahoo sample for yii-eauth extension php

Tags: php, oauth, yii, yahoo, yii-extensions

I'm looking for Yahoo oauth implementation for PHP yii-eauth extension.

Could you please share it or provide a sample code ? This implementation is absent in the standard suite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  HybridAuth, it works with all frameworks, and has a Yii Module.
http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/